# IBM WCS and DB2 : Want to export all catentries data from one DB and import into another DB

Tags: db2, websphere-7, websphere-commerce

Basically i have two environments, Production and QA. On QA DB, the data is not same as it is on production so my QA team is unable to test it properly. So want to import all catentries/products related data in QA DB from production. I searched a lot but not found any solution regarding this.

May be i need to find all product related tables and export them one by one and then import into dev db but not sure.

Can anyone please guide me regarding this. How i can do this activity with best practices?

I am using DB2

Comment: The data model is pretty well [documented in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.data.doc/refs/rdmcatent.htm?lang=en), so you can easily find all dependent tables.

Comment: @mustaccio, Great. Realy helpfull.. Can you please guide me how i can import these all data into my QA db. Is there any utility provided by IBM or i need to export individual table and import it in other DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebSphere Commerce [data model is documented](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.data.doc/refs/rdmcatent.htm?lang=en), which will help you identify all related tables. You can then use the DB2 [utility `db2move`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html?lang=en) to export (and later load) those tables in one shot. For example,

```
db2move yourdb export -sn yourschema -tn catentry,catentrel,catentdesc,catentattr
```

Be sure to list all tables you need, separated by commas with no spaces. You can specify patterns to match table names:

```
db2move yourdb export -sn yourschema -tn "catent*,listprice"
```

`db2move` will create a file `db2move.lst` that lists all extracted tables, so you can load all data with:

```
db2move yourQAdb load -lo replace
```

running from the same directory.